# Why was this question put on hold?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked [this](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/6313/what-spirits-are-made-in-cuba).

I'd like to know why this is considered too broad. To me, it seems that there either are other major types of liquor or there arent, its not too broad...

I'm not asking about individual breweries making individual spirits, but major types emblematic to Cuba.

Kinda like Sake for Japan, Cachaça for Brazil, Scotch in Scotland, etc.

Comment: Just FYI, I deleted the comment that didn't answer the question as unhelpful, and then your comment that was responding to that comment as obsolete.   Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have reevaluated your question and I agree that your question isn't too broad so i have re-opened that question for you i hope you get some good answers back and get what you are looking for